# how can i split date form Date of string formate using flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, sqlite

my date of string like (2009-12-03 21:05:00) date with time . so i used to store 
`var newdate:Date=new Date(Date.parse(startdate));` but shows some errors.

and also i tried to split string(date) used date function like

```
var datenumber:Number= (new Date(Date.parse(startdate))).getDate();
```

not get the date how can i split particular date only ? plz kindly refer me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the dashes (`-`). Use `2009/12/03 21:05:00` instead.

In the string given to the [Date.parse()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html#parse()) method, the year, month and day terms can be separated by a forward slash (`/`) or by spaces, but never by a dash (`-`). Supported formats include the following: (you can include partial representations of these formats; that is, just the month, day, and year)

> `Day Mon DD HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY`
>   `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TZD`
>   `HH:MM:SS TZD Day Mon/DD/YYYY`
>   `Mon DD YYYY HH:MM:SS TZD`
>   `Day Mon DD HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY`
>   `Day DD Mon HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY`
>   `Mon/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TZD`
>   `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS TZD`

You can change the format of the string using a simple regex:

```
dateString = dateString.replace(/-/g, "/");
```

Comment: this (2009-12-03 21:05:00) instead  got from webservice . so how can i changed to new format of '/' 2009/12/03 21:05:00